# Using a private variable in a public property getter

Tags: c#, properties

If I have a public property that only has a getter, is it correct to use a private variable to assign the value to then return that value or should I just use `return` rather then setting the value of `userID`? In the future we plan to add more functionality that will use the userID field, and Methods will be added to this class that use the userID field. Is there any benefit to one way or the other? Is there some other way that this should be done?

```
    private string userID;
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("UID"))
            {
                userID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UID"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                userID = "0000";
            }
            return userID;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The way the getter is coded right now does not need an assignment, because subsequent calls ignore the value set by previous methods. However, you could cache the result, like this:

```
private string userID;
public string ID {
    get {
        if (userID == null) {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("UID")) {
                userID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UID"].ToString();
            } else {
                userID = "0000";
            }
        }
        return userID;
    }
}
```

This implementation avoids reading the `"UID"` repeatedly by caching the result of the initial retrieval in a private instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this, but I personally would go, in this case, for a function.

The reason is simple: 
One when calls a `function`, **expects** that some computation may occur inside of it.

Instead when one calls a `property`, it's not something that he would expect to happen. When you call a property, you think you call some internal `field` wrapper.

Repeat, what you do *is* possible to do, but it's not so good from architectual point of view.

So, my suggession, for this case: use a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`

You are setting `userID` in the `get`

So

```
public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("UID"))
            {
                 return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["UID"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return "0000";
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, you are not persisting any data, therefore having a backing field of `userID` is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using public property, you can change implementation anytime. No userID variable is useless, if you will need it in the future you can always add it.